# Bokeh Multi-level dropdown menu

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, bokeh

I want to make a multi-level dropdown menu, something like the one in this XKCD:
[image]

Is there some way to have subcategories fold out like that using the Bokeh Dropdown menu?

My question is distinct from [Bokeh or HoloViews multiple depended dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010764) because I want a single dropdown with multiple levels, not N separate, inter-dependent dropdown menus. I also don't intend to put this Dropdown in a notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh `1.4.0`, there is nothing built into the core library for this.

That is the short answer, but it's worth mentioning that Bokeh is extensible, so it's possible that you could wrap some JS widget and use it in Bokeh apps and docs. You can find more information about creating custom extensions here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html

Comment: Would this be something you'd consider putting in the core library?